# sendmail failover procedure

Tags: sendmail, failover

How does sendmail failover procedure may look like?
I have to deploy couple of MTA servers using sendmail. I have redundant servers on site using SAN disks to store sendmail queues. What to do if one of my hosts goes down? What with messages still pending in sendmail queues. Can such queue be simply copied to second sendmail host and there it will be properly handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you read the [bat book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596510299.do) so that you grasp a clear understanding of how sendmail queues work. Yes, it is possible to copy queues from one sendmail to another (by hand if needed) and then run them. But YMMV depending on how they are setup.